# Не применяются CSS стили к footer.php

Tags: css, wordpress

Проблема в стилях в WP только футера. Вызываю футер `<?php get_footer(); ?>` но на сайте не применяются стили к футеру. В чем может быть проблема? [сайт.](http://yurist.tj/)

Comment: ну так смотрите по селекторам на какие элементы вешаете. у вас атрибут id=main не уникальный, исправьте

Comment: а что исправлять то? всмысле, повторение id - шника?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищите в css файле `.form__widget_left2 {width:50%;float:left;"}`

Там кавычки есть, которые портят весь последующий код css